# How do I delete all text before and after a specific naming convention appears in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

This is what I want to do:

**BEFORE:**

```
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private 
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/AVCHD    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/AVCHD/BDMV    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/AVCHD/BDMV/CLIPINF    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/AVCHD/BDMV/PLAYLIST    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/AVCHD/BDMV/STREAM    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/Converted    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/M4ROOT    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/M4ROOT/CLIP    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/M4ROOT/GENERAL    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/M4ROOT/SUB    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/M4ROOT/THMBNL    
AVCHD/2017-08-25/20170824_GV_GLW_C102/private/SONY    
AVCHD/2017-08-24/20170822_GV_GLW_C099/PRIVATE/AVCHD/BDMV/STREAM    
AVCHD/2017-08-24/20170822_GV_GLW_C099/PRIVATE/Converted    
AVCHD/2017-08-24/20170822_GV_GLW_C099/PRIVATE/M4ROOT    
AVCHD/2017-08-24/20170822_GV_GLW_C099/PRIVATE/M4ROOT/CLIP    
AVCHD/2017-08-24/20170822_GV_GLW_C099/PRIVATE/M4ROOT/GENERAL    
AVCHD/2017-08-24/20170822_GV_GLW_C099/PRIVATE/M4ROOT/SUB    
AVCHD/2017-08-24/20170822_GV_GLW_C099/PRIVATE/M4ROOT/THMBNL    
AVCHD/2017-08-24/20170822_GV_GLW_C099/PRIVATE/SONY
```

**AFTER:**

```
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170824_GV_GLW_C102    
20170822_GV_GLW_C099    
20170822_GV_GLW_C099    
20170822_GV_GLW_C099    
20170822_GV_GLW_C099    
20170822_GV_GLW_C099    
20170822_GV_GLW_C099    
20170822_GV_GLW_C099    
20170822_GV_GLW_C099
```

I will then delete all duplicates once I'm able to reduce the directory paths down to their parent folder names as seen here.

The parent folders are always containing this exact structure: 'XXXXXXXX_XX_XXX_XXXX'

I need to delete all text before and after that structure appears, leaving behind only the parent folder name

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the find and replace function of Notepad++, with [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/).
Depending on how the folder names are set, you can use something like this in the search box (this is a pretty ugly expression, but it works with your example.):

```
.*?(\d{8}_[A-Z]{2}_[A-Z]{3}_[A-Z]\d{3}).*
```

In the 'replace with' box you can put

```
\1
```

Explanation of the expression:

- `.*` takes any number of any characters. The question mark after that
  tells uses lazy matching
- `\d{8}` matches 8 digits
- `_` matches an underscore
- `[A-Z]{2}` matches exactly 2 capital letters
- The area between the brackets makes a capture group that you can use as a value to do the replace

Comment: This worked! I may need to ammend the amounts within { } to match with other roll names but it works like a charm! Thank You!

Comment: Glad that helps! If you need to match both digits and characters you can use (as an example for the characters after the last underscore) [A-Za-z0-9]{4}

Answer (score 0):

Find With:

```
^.+/(\d{8}_.{2}_.{3}_.{4})/.+$
```

Replace With:

```
$1
```

Replace All